# How to pass a value to a class from another file or command prompt

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have written a java program to merge multiple excel sheets into one excel and generated jar, and i run it using java -jar Merge_Excel.jar.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class Csv_Merge {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        try{

            File folder = new File("c:/test/");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();

            for (File file : listOfFiles) {


                if (file.isFile()) {

                    String thisline;
                    ArrayList<String> al = null;
                    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

                    HSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet(file.getName());
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

                    while ((thisline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        al = new ArrayList<String>();
                        String strar[] = thisline.split(",");

                        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                            for (int k = 1; k < arlist.size(); k++) {

                                ArrayList<String> ardata = (ArrayList<String>) arlist.get(k);

                                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) k);


                                for (int p = 0; p < ardata.size(); p++) {

                                    HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) p);
                                    cell.setCellValue(ardata.get(p).toString());

                                }
                            }

                            al.add(strar[j]);

                        }

                        arlist.add(al);
                    }

                    fis.close();
                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:/test/new.xls");
                    workbook.write(fileOut);

                    fileOut.flush();
                    fileOut.close();
                    br.close();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");

        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            System.out.println(ex);

        }
    }
}
```

I need to pass the location of excel path `File folder = new File("c:/test/");` and the new merged file path `FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:/test/new.xls");` from command prompt or from different file ,just the path.

Is there any way to do it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the directory path from command while running jar and can access that directory in main java program simply executing following steps :

1) java -jar program-name.jar c:/test/

2)

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
         String folderName = args[0];
         File folder = new File(folderName);
         File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    }
```

Comment: I am getting this error after making those changes java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: @Pavan which index you are accessing it should be 0 otherwise ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will generate.

Comment: i modified like this 

`try{

            String folderName = args[0];
            File folder = new File(folderName);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();`

Comment: Can you modify that code in the question so that i can check if i have made any mistakes.

Comment: the error appears when i enter this part of code
`String folderName = args[0];
         File folder = new File(folderName);`

Answer (score 0):

Well one of the way to do it using command line arguments by passing that path to main function and you should be good.